# Проблема с циком While на Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

хотел написать простую программу по поиску НОК двух выбранных чисел:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())

cr = False
i = 0

while cr:
    if (i % a == 0) and (i % b == 0):
        print(i)
        cr = True
    
    i += 1
```

Однако столкнулся с тем, что цикл просто не выводит результат ни в каком случае.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Хотелось бы понять почему цикл ничего не выводит.

Comment: @Unslath потому что изначально `cr = False`, получается `while False`, и в цикл даже не заходит. True и False поменяйте местами, или условие цикла поменяйте на `not cr`.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь работает.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл не начнётся, т.к. `cr` у тебя изначально `False`

Comment: Но у меня же есть условие по которому у меня значение цикла может стать истинным и по идее цикл должен завершиться.

Comment: While - пока, пока cr у тебя true, цикл будет выполнятся, а если он изначально false, то он никогда и не запустится